# How to get versionName from AppAppdateInfo

Tags: android, in-app-update

I'm trying to implement Android InApp Update, one of my conditions to show the Flexible popup is to check if the user version is two times behind the play store version.
The problem is in my build.gradle the version code is generated dynamically and it doesn't reflect the version number, I need to check the version names instead.
AppInfoUpdate is not returning the version name, and here is my question:

How to get the playstore version name from AppUpdateInfo, if it's not possible is there an API I can use to retrieve it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: did you find it?

Comment: No, I ended up using the version code rather than versionCode

Comment: It's insane to me that they don't also include the `versionName`. We use that to determine how impactful an update may be and if a long database migration or sync is required afterward, so we can warn the User ahead of time. Crazy. If this ever changes, somebody please leave a comment here. Thanks.